# kineticjs canvas overlapping another canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm attempting to build an application that uses KineticJS to overlap another element. Ideally the background application could be simply another div with a photo in it or something as complex as Google Maps.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a proof of concept where I could basically have a KineticJS canvas that overlaps another element and allows it to overlap the other element but have all input go directly to the KineticJS object only.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvasBottom" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    <div id="container" width=300 height=200></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS to put the Kinetic container div directly on to of a canvas element**

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
#canvasBottom, #container{
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**JS to use the container div**

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 300,
    height: 200
});
```